# Printing sequence of different print commands in python

Tags: python

I have four sentences which i want to print out eg.

```
print 'I am  here'
print 'I like spring'
print 'My house has two floors'
print 'Sun is bright'
```

I want to make program print them out in different sequence every time i run the program. Which is the best way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Put them into an array, randomly shuffle the array, and then print the array in sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) for this. It takes a list and shuffles it into a random order (like a deck of cards). Then, you can print them out just like any other list (with the for-loop).

This will require you to put them into a list of strings first, instead of just having the print statements.

```
import random
ss = ['I am here', 'I like spring', 'My house has two floors', 'Sun is bright']
random.shuffle(ss)
for s in ss:
    print s
```

---

Here is a cute way of doing it in one line. It uses sorting on a random key to shuffle the list, then uses `.join` to combine the four strings with newlines... and then printing it out. I suggest you use my first suggestion, not this.

```
import random
print '\n'.join(sorted(['I am here', 'I like spring', 'My house has two floors', 'Sun is bright'], key=lambda *args: random.random()))
```